# What is the iOS 6.0 user agent string?

Tags: ios

Previous user-agent strings:

IOS 5.1 - What is the iOS 5.1 user agent string?
iOS 5.0 - What is the iOS 5.0 user agent string?
iOS 4.0 - What is the iPhone 4 user-agent?

Answer (score 0):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10A5376e
```